# When import phonegap project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-build

I have created a successful project using CLI but when I import it then it does not show the select button.  Whats gone wrong please ? [image]

Comment: the reason is the workspace already contains the project with same name.. it will work if you change the workspace

Answer (score -1):

Like Mohammed said, you cannot import a new project to a work space if there is already a project with same name.

Please refer the screenshot to change the import project name. Click the first text bar with red border then click the second text bar with red border, now you can edit the project name that you were importing.

[image]